# Gnuplot: Increase graph width

Tags: gnuplot

I run a script to generate a 2 dimensional graph.png with gnuplot from a  dataset.
I want the width of the graph to increase with more data
e.g. width = 30px * (entries in the dataset).

How to do I set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use the `stats` feature (you'll need version >=4.6 I think)

```
...
stats "file1.dat" using 2 name "FILE1"
set term png size (30*FILE1_records),400
...
```

Comment: Works for me. Thanks!